# Entity framework several removes + updates "already being tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi, dto

Here is my code :

```
public async Task<int> UpdateTransport(int transportId, TransportForUpdateDto transportDto)
{
    var transportCheck = await _context.Transport
        .Where(t => t.TransportId == transportId)
        .Include(t => t.Loadings)
        .Include(t => t.Deliveries)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    var loadingsToDelete = transportCheck.Loadings.Where(tc => !transportDto.Loadings.Any(l => l.LoadingId == tc.LoadingId)).ToList();
    var deliveriesToDelete = transportCheck.Deliveries.Where(tc => !transportDto.Deliveries.Any(d => d.DeliveryId == tc.DeliveryId)).ToList();

    _context.Loading.RemoveRange(loadingsToDelete);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    _context.Delivery.RemoveRange(deliveriesToDelete);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    var transport = await _context.Set<Transport>().Where(t => t.TransportId == transportId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    _mapper.Map(transportDto, transport);

    return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

It's pretty simple. I am just checking if objects in DB are existing in Dto as Deliveries and Loadings. if not, I delete them in the database. The problem is that I got an Entity Framework error :

> The instance of entity type 'Delivery' cannot be tracked because
>   another instance with the key value '{DeliveryId: 19619}' is already
>   being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one
>   entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Sorry for my lack of knowledge about Entity Framework.. I really don't know how to solve my problem.

Edit: After many tries, I see that I got the error only if I call the route in Postman for the first time. The next call is OK, entity is updated correctly.
Problem comes from the last line :

```
return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Bumped back into view by the revision. Any progress on this in the past 5 weeks?

Comment: Should probably wrap that lot in a transaction